# Magento 2 caching Web Service response

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cache, web-services

I have a problem, whenever a user finalizes a purchase he is sent to an order tracker page. When this page is first opened it posts the order to a custom web service.

There is an IF that checks if the order already exists so it wont post it again. The problem is that the first time I open it, the order is posted correctly in the database. But if I refresh the page, it still says that the order does not exist, this happens until I run sudo bin/magento-cli setup:upgrade.

Here's the code that check if the order exists:

```
public function checkIfExists()
{   
    if (empty($_GET['orderId'])) {
        $orderId=$this->_order->getId();
        //validate customer and load order based on Id            
    } else {
        $orderId = $_GET['orderId'];
    }

    // $orderId = $this->_order->getId();
    $username = 'sixtogo-admin';
    $password = 'Af/$k!QWx76S72sX';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://sixtogo.herokuapp.com/consultaestatus?no_sap=300986724&org_code=169&ticket=" . $orderId);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $jsonArray = json_decode($response, true);  

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
        // echo 'RESPONSE: ' . $response;
    }
    echo count($jsonArray);
    //By americo ft. Kalev
    if (count($jsonArray)>0) {
       echo "Order exists, wont post";
        return true;
    } 
    echo "Order does not exists, will post";
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what is the problem.Donot understand what  you issue facing

Comment: PHP variable wont refresh until i run magento setup:upgrade. For example if I print current time at 08:37, it shows 08:37, but if I refresh page in 5 minutes it still says 08:37